# Entity Framework query with navigation property and without navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, query-performance

Below are my two model classes:

```
public partial class Region
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SubRegions_Coordinates> SubRegions_Coordinates { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubRegions_Coordinates
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> RegionId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AreaId { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }

        public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
        public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

Query:

```
var query = from r in context.Region
            select new 
            {
               Latitude = r.SubRegions_Coordinates.
                          Where(sb =>sb.AreaId== 100).Select(sb=>sb.Latitude).FirstOrDefault(),
            }

var query = from r in context.Region
            select new 
            {
                 Latitude = context.SubRegions_Coordinates.Where(sb => sb.RegionId == r.Id && sb.AreaId == 100).
                            Select(sb => sb.Latitude).FirstOrDefault(),
               }
```

Above are my two queries which are basically fetching latitudes for each of the regions for a specific `Areaid = 100`.

But I do not understand which of the above two queries will be better for performance and why.

Which query should I use?

Comment: Why can't you run both and see yourself which is faster?

Comment: [Don’t Use LINQ’s Join. Navigate!](https://dzone.com/articles/don%E2%80%99t-use-linq%E2%80%99s-join-navigate)

Comment: Run sql profiler while you are running each query. That is the only definitive way of knowing what SQL Server is actually doing

Comment: Basically, they will most likely end in the same SQL query (again, you can check this yourself). But the first is using the ORM for the job for which it was designed. The second is doing the work of the ORM yourself.

Comment: @TimRogers:So from the performance point of view there is no difference.It is just that with the help of navagation property
code is easier to read.Something like that??

Comment: @Learning Yes. But always verify performance yourself if you're concerned.